# Changing instance variables

Tags: python, class, variables

I have this code:

```
class Yes:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=1

    def yes(self):
        if self.a==1:
            print "Yes"
        else:
            print "No, but yes"

class No(Yes):
    def no(self):
        if self.a==1:
            print "No"
        else:
            print "Yes, but no"
        self.a-=1 #Note this line
```

Now, while running:

```
Yes().yes()
No().no()
Yes().yes()
No().no()
```

I want it to print out:

```
Yes
No
No, but yes
Yes, but no
```

It gives me:

```
Yes
No
Yes
No
```

I know the reason is that I'm only changing the value of `self.a` in the `No` class. Is there any way to change it in the Yes class while still in the `No` class (like if there was something that I could plug in in place of the `self.a-=1` that would work)?

Comment: you can write a setter method in the class , and call it from the other class

Comment: I tried that, it keeps calling back self.a=1

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python

Comment: @MichalČihař in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69067/673991) gets to the heart of the problem here: **you cannot set a class variable through `self`**.  You must use the _class name_ instead. The confusion comes from being able to _get_ a class variable through `self`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not sure what possible use you have for this, but...

You want to manipulate a *class* variable, but you keep addressing instance variables. If you want a class variable, use a class variable!

```
class Yes:
    a = 1 # initialize class var.
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1 # point of this is what?

    def yes(self):
        if Yes.a==1: # check class var
            print "Yes"
        else:
            print "No, but yes"

class No(Yes):

    def no(self):
        if Yes.a==1: # check class var
            print "No"
        else:
            print "Yes, but no"
        Yes.a-=1 # alter class var
```

Comment: I was using it as an example for something else I was trying to do, thank you

Comment: Using class vars like this seems like code smell. Are you sure what you are doing can't be accomplished some other way?

Comment: @FrancisAvila I think you were thrown off by his setting `a` in the constructor. He was merely trying to demonstrate a method changing the value of a class variable. The answer to that would have been `Yes.a = 1`. [Moral of the story](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69067/673991), you can get a class variable through self, but you can't set it that way.

Comment: @BobStein Thanks for pointing out that distinction. still bugs me!

Comment: @SujayPhadke it's a recurring trauma for me too. Perennial Python pitfall: attempting to **set a class property via `self`**.

Comment: @BobStein Wonder why python allows it. Ambiguity is not Pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

It appears what you want to use is a static variable rather than an instance variable. A static variable is shared between all the instances of the class.

```
class Yes:
    a = 1
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def yes(self):
        if Yes.a==1:
            print "Yes"
        else:
            print "No, but yes"

class No(Yes):

    def no(self):
        if Yes.a==1:
            print "No"
        else:
            print "Yes, but no"
        Yes.a-=1 #Note this line

Yes().yes()
No().no()
Yes().yes()
No().no()
```

Will output:

```
Yes
No
No, but yes
Yes, but no
```

Comment: This is not a static variable, it's a class variable. If it changes, it changes for the class.